# check spamassassin DNSBL results

Tags: centos, email, spamassassin, rbl

Is there a way to check the results of spamassassin on an email when it checks DNSBL?
I see nothing in the maillog and nothing in the mail header.
I do not know if it is actually querying the DNSBLs or not, which I would like to know.

I currently have spamassassin 3.3.1 setup on Centos 6.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute spamassassin with debugging/tracking dns queries.  It will track dnsbl (and dnswl) queries.

```
spamassassin -D dns < mail_message_file
```